# no result values expectedcompilerWrongResultCount

Tags: go

I have this two functions

```
func fib_memo(n int) {
    memo := make([]int, n+1)
    return fib_2(n, memo)
}
func fib_2(n int, memo []int) int {
    result := 0
    if &memo[n] != nil {
        return memo[n]
    }
    if n == 1 || n == 2 {
        result = 1
    } else {
        result = fib_2(n-1, memo) + fib_2(n-2, memo)
        memo[n] = result
    }
    return result
}
```

But the first in giving me a compiler error i don't no why please help : no result values expectedcompilerWrongResultCount

Comment: `fib_memo()` does not have result parameters, so you can't return from it what `fib_2()` returns.

Comment: gotcha! Sorry for the dumb question, sometimes everything you need is a vision of outside.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
func fib_memo(n int) (result int) {
    memo := make([]int, n+1)
    return fib_2(n, memo)
}
```